# Unable to runserver with docker-compose up

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker while development. I noticed that I can't launch dev server with `docker-compose up` command, but can with `docker-compose run`

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /opt/lib
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /opt/web
```

Here is docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: ./web/
    working_dir: /opt/web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./web:/opt/web
    user: 1000:1000
    depends_on:
      - database
    env_file: env
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000

  database:
    image: mdillon/postgis:9.6
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./database/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Now, if I run `docker-compose up`, only database starts up:
[image]

But with `docker-compose run` server starts fine:
[image]

If I change docker-compose.yml > services > web > command to `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn project.wsgi:application -w 4 -b :3000` it also works fine, but I need autorestart when files change
[image]

I use Docker for MacOS `Version 18.03.1-ce-mac65 (24312)`, 
`Django==1.10`

I tried to reset it to factory settings and this did not help.

Can you help me with this?

**EDIT 1:**

Other manage.py commands, like *migrate*, work fine

Comment: the ENTRYPOINT in python:3.6 is python and not shell (or bash) so you dont have to run python again, i think you could try just `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000`

Comment: @MazelTov yep, may be. But this does not help, anyway

Comment: what is the output of `docker-compose up web`?

Comment: @MazelTov nothing after `Attaching to mein-dach-web_web_1`. Seems like it just hangs. `docker exec <container id> ps` outputs: 

  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 python
   51 ?        00:00:02 python
   99 ?        00:00:00 ps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the `./manage.py runserver` requires to Allocate a pseudo-TTY. You can pass it to docker-compose.yml this way

```
services:
  web:
    tty: true
    command: ./manage.py runserver 0:3000
```

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned later, you should specify the command in compose file, but with `reload` option.

Like this:

`command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn project.wsgi:application -w 4 -b :3000 --reload`

[official docs ref](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#reload)

Comment: @atomAltera `runserver` is a development server and should not be used in production

Comment: @Zulu, I need it for development

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I faced this problem only on the very first `docker-compose up` run. It happened because DB initialization took too long. So just press `Ctrl-C` and run `docker-compose up` again.

`depends_on` does not really monitor the DB-server status — it monitors container status. So it starts your web app before the DB is really ready for connection.

And yes, `tty: true` suggested by Mazel Tov is very useful. Without it, you won't see the Django error message (I don't know why) which would help you to understand the issue.