# dockerize django, manage.py runserver: error: unrecognized arguments:

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to dockerize an existing django application. I am using django with a virtualenv and a pipfile.

So my dockerfile looks:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8000
# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add linux-headers postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt . 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
# copy project
COPY . .
# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

python manage.py flush --no-input
python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

and docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  app:
   build:
     context: .
     args:
       - DEV=true
   ports:
      - "8000:8000"
   volumes:
      - .:/app
   command: >
      sh -c "python ./manage.py migrate &&      
             python ./manage.py runserver 192.168.1.135:8000"
   env_file:
      - ./.env

   depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - dev-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
      
volumes:
    dev-db-data:
    dev-static-data:
```

and settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.135']

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [   
    "http://192.168.1.135:8000"    
]
```

so the url is on the whitelist.

But when I do docker-compose up. I still get this error:

```
manage.py runserver: error: unrecognized arguments: 192.168.1.135:8000
```

Question: how to dockerize an existing django application?

Comment: You have `runserver` twice in your command. Maybe that's already the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an error in your docker-compose code, try:

```
python ./manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

It's related to this question:

[Unable to runserver with docker-compose up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229873/unable-to-runserver-with-docker-compose-up)

Comment: Oke, that was a mistake from my side. But then I stil get this: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
dwl_backend-app-1  | Error: That IP address can't be assigned to.

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC. yes, oke. But I am working with a front-end emulator. So I need the address:  http://192.168.1.135:8000. Otherwise the front-end can't communicate with the backend

Comment: It supposed to use your localhost.

Comment: Oke, But I already have a super user. But when I insert the credentials in the admin panel of django I get Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.  How to make the migrations in the docker container?

Comment: @Eddudos.But how can I use the ip 192.168.1.135:8000?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146327/how-to-start-a-dockerized-django-server-with-custom-ip-address

Have you tried this?